# Adding Greek letters to LaTeX code while creating documentation for an R package

Tags: r, latex

I'm making a new package for R and I want to include the table generated by the following code in the documentation:

```
\tabular{cccc}{
sign beta \tab sign gamma \tab K \tab g \cr
+ \tab + \tab 0 \tab -1 \cr
+ \tab - \tab -2pi \tab 1 \cr
- \tab + \tab -pi \tab 1 \cr
- \tab - \tab -pi \tab -1
}
```

However, I would like the words 'beta', 'gamma' and 'pi' to be replaced by actual corresponding Greek letters. How can I do this? I've tried the following:

```
$\beta$
```

and the following:

```
$\\beta$
```

but it doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wrap it in an equation macro like this `\eqn{\gamma}` it should work.

Further info in the `roxygen2` [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd-formatting.html).

Also, additional information can be found in the [Rd format documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Mathematics) of the R Extensions page.

Answer (score 1):

As of `roxygen2` version 6.0.0 (released early 2017) you can also place the characters directly into the text as they are left as is.

That is characters typed or pasted directly into the `roxygen2` comment section like `α`, `β` and `γ` get rendered both within the internal R documentation and also in generated docs using tools such as `pkgdown`.

The change that determines this is the support of CommonMark described in the `roxygen2` [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd-formatting.html), with the relevant section about the support of these characters available in the [Commonmark Spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#textual-content)

Answer (score -1):

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

```
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \(\beta\)  &\(\gamma\) & \( \kappa\) & g \\
    &  & \( \theta\) &  -1 \\
    + & - & -2\(pi\)&  1\\ 
    - & + & -\(pi\)& 1 \\
    - & - & -\(pi\) & -1\\
```

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
Here I have used primitive form of tabulation. It works

Comment: What are the chances that this works with this r package documentation if `$\beta$` evidently does not work?